# how to debug program with argument vector in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I'm new in OS X.
I'm writing programs with UNIX system calls in Xcode.
I'd like to debug program with argument vector line by line.
But I don't know how I can put argument value into **argv.

Assume that executable file has the name 'a.out', which I want to debug line by line in Xcode. All I have to do is let the program be initially set argv to the following.

```
argv[0] = "./a.out"
argv[1] = "ls"
argv[2] = "foo"
argv[3] = "-l"
```

What Should I do? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what you want to do. There's an issue with your code though, your strings are using single quotes instead of double. Single quotes are for characters, double quotes are for strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you want to pass in arguments to your program when you debug? If so, click on the name of your target in the drop-down menu next to Run and Stop, go down to "Edit Scheme...", and then click on the arguments tab. You can add arguments to pass in there.